# Convert file contents to lowercase and store result in same file

Tags: linux, command-line, tr

I use the following command to convert my input file contents to lowercase

```
tr A-Z a-z < input > output
```

This command works fine.

But when I try to store the output in input file itself, it is not working.
The input file is empty after executing the command. Why?

```
 tr A-Z a-z < input > input
```

Comment: Note [this answer to one of the proposed duplicates in particular](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/73093), but the answers to this question give an actual solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But when I try to store the output in input file itself, it is not working. The input file is empty after executing the command. Why?

Because the `> input` causes the shell to truncate the file before the `tr` command is run. Incidentially, you can get around this with more advanced descriptor handling in `Bash`:

```
exec 8<>input
exec 9<>input
tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <&8 >&9
```

The `exec #<>file` opens a file into descriptor `#` in read-write mode without truncating.

Comment: It should be noted that this technique will work reliably only for commands like `tr` (*without* the `-d` or `-s` option) that write out exactly as much data as they read in, on a one-for-one basis.

Answer (score 8):

If you have GNU `sed` you can use

```
sed -i 's/.*/\L&/' input
```

- `-i` modify file in place
- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `.*` any characters on each line
- `\L` lowercase
- `&` the matched pattern